# Does Firefox use OCSP?

Tags: firefox, ocsp, crl

And if it does use Online Certificate Status Protocol, is there a way to disable it, so that it uses CRL instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable it:

> To disable OCSP in Firefox:
>
> Go to "Tools (or Menu button) -> Options -> Advanced -> Certificates" and uncheck `Query OCSP responder servers to confirm the current validity of certificates`.

(source: http://kb.mozillazine.org/OCSP_error_when_accessing_secure_sites)